# visual studio 2010 setup project - removing dynamic data

Tags: setup-project

My program generating data while running and saving it in files in programs folder.

On uninstall, those files remain. Is there any way to remove them without using custom action?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Installer removes only the files it installs. For application files it supports [file removal operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371201%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?ppud=4). However, this feature is not supported by Visual Studio setup projects.

So you either use an uninstall custom action or you switch to a setup authoring tool which supports file removals.